# dialogflow api does not request my webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to request my dialogflow agent through its api.

Here is my code:

```
const request = require('request');
const _ = require('underscore');

const apiBase = 'https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query/';
const token = ...;

let options = { 
    'url': apiBase,
    'headers': {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    },  
    'json': {
        'v': '20150910',
        'lang': 'fr',
        'sessionId': 'abcdefgh'
    },  
}


    let query = 'welcome_intent';

    options.json.query = query;
    request.post(options , (e, r, b) => {
        console.log('result: ', b.result)
    });
```

The string 'welcome_intent' has been added to the user says of the welcomeIntent. I get the following result:

```
result: 
   { source: 'agent',
     resolvedQuery: 'welcome_intent',
     speech: '',
     action: 'intent.welcome',
     parameters: {},
     metadata: 
      { inputContexts: [],
        outputContexts: [],
        intentName: 'welcomeIntent',
        intentId: '104a6251-fa1a-404a-a042-dfa1ce9118a8',
        webhookUsed: 'true',
        webhookForSlotFillingUsed: 'false',
        contexts: [Array] },
     score: 1 },
```

It triggers the correct intent which should use the webhook to fulfill the answer. But it does not actually request my webhook. It is said in [this doc](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query#get_and_post_responses) that I should have a field fulfilment in my result json. I don't have this field.

Am I doing something wrong ? I can make a subsequent call to my webhook using the DF result, but can I avoid it ?

thanks